# Dynamically change og:description dynamically with php

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Hi I´m having a hard time getting my og metatags to change dynamically( banging my head against the wall). I want to change the og:description dynamically based on an input field.

Here is what I have been able do figure out so far:

$og_description = $_POST['question'];

$custom_input = array("value" => $og_description);

```
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site name etc.. " />

<meta property="og:description" content="   <?php echo "this is {$custom_input['value']} !"; ?>" />
```

It works just fine outside the meta tags, but for some reason I just end up with it echoing the text "this is".

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Where is $custom_input['value'] coming from? That value presumably won't be set when Facebook's crawler is reading your site

Comment: I created it as a variable above the OG: tags. It basically fetces content from the input field on my form. Im not sure if I need it at all - what I want is to use this variable as the description . $og_description = $_POST['question'];.

Comment: Yes, but when Facebook's crawler is accessing that URL to get the metadata there won't be any form input; it will be a simple GET request to that URL

Comment: That makes sense, but I allways try to lint the URL after I have submitted the form - wich should work?

Comment: no, Facebook's crawler makes a new request to the URL to get the metadata, so your script, when responding to Facebook, won't have the same session or POST information as any previous request to that URL